# google play store rejected my app due to sms permission

Tags: android

i removed sms permission from manifest but playstore not accepting my app
manifest set only readsms permission. but playstore rejected this app
i am getting this mail from play store

**The declared functionality Default SMS handler (and any other core functionality usage while default handler)  is determined to be unnecessary or not aligned with the core functionality of your app.Under the SMS / Call Log policy only apps with specific core functionalities are eligible to request SMS / Call Log permissions. For the list of eligible core functionalities refer to this Help Center article.You can come into compliance by either removing the permission from your app or revising your app so that its core functionality (through in-app experience and meta data in Store listing) aligns with the eligible cases.
Default handler capability was listed on your declaration form, but your app has no default handler capability.**

mainfest permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
```

please help me to solve this problem

Comment: its new policy by google https://github.com/opendatakit/collect/issues/2738 take a look here it might help

Comment: You cant use it if your app dosent need it for core functionality

Comment: we have read sms for otp in core functionality.

Comment: for that use SMSretriver API or firbase phoneAuth

Comment: if else ou need to contact google for exceptin

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54638861/why-i-am-receiving-warning-this-app-does-not-meet-google-play-permissions-poli/54666518?noredirect=1#comment96198733_54666518

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it concerns Google Play Store policies and procedures, rather than programming. Please refer to: [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?‍](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165), [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746), and [the Help Center page regarding appropriate topics for this site](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

According to google "You may only request permissions that are necessary to implement critical current features or services in your application. You may not use permissions that give access to user or device data for undisclosed, unimplemented, or disallowed features or purposes".

[Click Here To Read Official Google Permission Doc](https://play.google.com/about/privacy-security-deception/permissions/)

**If your app need to read sms for SMS-based user verification / OTP verification please use [SMS Retriever API](https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever/overview)** which does not needed any sms permission and your app can still read SMS for OTP verification.

Comment: hope this will helpful for you , please verify my answer as correct.

Comment: Even if i remove permission and build it, again it adds the permission in manifest file.I have not mentioned in config file for sms feature.Can you please tell from where it is adding it again after build?

Comment: do you use any third party library?
in your case it might be possible any library using by you needed permission for SMS .

Comment: I am using cordova plugin compat.Is this causing problem?There is no mention for sms plugin in config file,package.json file.Still it is giving me this error "Cannot find plugin.xml for plugin "cordova-sms-plugin". Please try adding it again."

Comment: some of your library or package is needed SMS permission , you have to find out this

Comment: @SachinHR there is an issue on playstore 
so First upload the apk (it will show you Waring about SMS permission but ignore it and continue) and after that again give a updated version and this time you surprise that there is no waring , it seems to be bug in playstore .
Try it and let me know if it works

Comment: Thanks for the response:). Actually i solved it by removing a plugin called cordova-plugin-tts(talk to speech).That was the plugin which was adding sms and call permission to manifest file.Now I am able to upload to play store after removing tts plugin from config file.

Comment: @Sachin HR how did you find that?

Comment: I have been looking for a tutorial in Kotlin for default SMS hander. Cannot find one yet. Been struggling to find one. Can you please share a link to complete tutorial if you know any?

Answer (score 6):

I also had this problem, I removed sms permissions in manifest,I tried whole day its rejected again and again, so I deleted all part of the code and I published only splash screen and login page, so my app is successfully published, and I updated my full project in next version, my application is live now.

Comment: So you publish your app with only the splash screen and then you pushed an update with the sms permissions etc. The updated version was rejected?

Comment: My version was already in playstore but when I add the SMS feature in my latest version which was struck by review team

Answer (score 2):

Google have declare new policy about use of sensitive permission in your android apps. now days lot of app related this **call** and **SMS** read permission used apps removing from play store. there is options way to use it [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54743611/8265484)

Answer (score 2):

Google play have a new policy for sensitive permissions such as **call** and **SMS**
If the core functionality of your app is not sms, then you do not need to request for that permission. you can send the sms using the default sms app on the device. use Intent.ACTION_VIEW like the code shown below. Then remove those permissions in your manifest file

```
    String intro="[INTRO MESSAGE]\n";
    String phoneNumber="12345678"
    Uri sms_uri = Uri.parse("smsto:" +phoneNumber);
    Intent sms_intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, sms_uri);
    sms_intent.setData(sms_uri);
    sms_intent.putExtra("sms_body", intro);
    startActivity(sms_intent);
```

Answer (score 2):

Go to your google play console. Then "store presence" and finally to "App Content"
Uncheck  "Default SMS handler" under core functionalities

Comment: i am using Firebase authentication using OTP if i remove default sms handler check the google will still reject the app as i have those permissions in my manifest. So the question is do i need to check any other option.